# How to run SQL query with parameters from a view that contains a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view of Cabinets and wish to display a list of RFID tags that have the same data center and location as the Cabinets.  I can't figure out the syntax for the command to find all the FRID records that fit the criteria.  The RFID display is designed as a partial of the cabinet view folder.  The command should get records where rfid.data_center = cabinet.data_center AND rfid.position = cabinet.cabinet_name.  If I hardcode the strings in it works.  Here's the code:

```
<% @cabinet.devices.order(:name).each do |device| %>
    <% @rfid = Rfid.where("(@rfid.data_center_name = '%#{params[:data_center]}%') AND (@rfid.position = '%#{params[:cabinet_name]}%')").uniq %>
```

Comment: What do your models look like?  What the relation between cabinet,device and RFID?

Answer (score 1):

What you have above is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to use parameter binding instead of doing the binding yourself with strings.  Here is one way to do that:

```
Rfid.where(:data_center_name => params[:data_center], :position => params[:cabinet_name]).uniq
```

Given what you have above, you might want something like this:

```
<% @cabinet.devices.order(:name).each do |device| %>
  <% @rfids = Rfid.where(:data_center_name => device.cabinet.datacenter, :position => device.cabinet.cabinet_name).uniq %>
```

There are better ways to write this, but we'd need to see your relationships and have a better idea of what you are trying to do.